# React-native component cache (or prevent unmounting) (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, caching, react-navigation, react-component

So my question is quite simple.

I have a navigation by react-navigation. Scenario

1. navigate from screen A to screen B.
   - each components in screen B are mounting / creating
2. go back from B to A
   - each components from screen B are unmounting
3. navigate once again from A to B
   - each components from screen B are mounting again.

IS there any way to prevent that? Data are not a problem, Im keeping them in redux store. The case is with components.

In my app user will keep switching between two screens, and I do not want to build one of them every single time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try a custom navigator ?

Comment: Yes, I did try building a custom navigator, but I was hoping for a relatively easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a perfect solution,

But I have also searched a lot but could not find this thing to work.

So as handy trick, you can use any **Tab Navigator** and hide the Tab Bar.

Because There is only **Tab Navigator** which maintains all screens in its stack even if you left the screen.

See this,

```
export const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
    Home: {
           screen: Home,
           navigationOptions: () => {
               return { tabBarVisible: false };
           },
    }
    Dashboard: {
           screen: Dashboard,
           navigationOptions: () => {
               return { tabBarVisible: false };
           },
    }
)
```

This will maintain all screens in Tab and you'll also not see any Tabs.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Problem with the `TabNavigator` is that I won't have the back navigation and the 'swipe to go back' functionality. Also in my design there already is a tabbar and having a nested tabbar and then changing settings (like the title) will affect both tabbars. It's just to much of a hassle. I want to have the screen slide in and slide out on back navigation and this does not seem possible with the tab navigator.